# VizFrame stacked bar chart legend order

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In the SAPUI5 [vizframe stacked bar chart example](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame/sample/sap.viz.sample.StackedBar), the order of the stacked bar is not matching with the order of the legend by default.

> [image: SAPUI5 Viz Frame Stacked Bar order issue]

In the above examples, the bar displays '1 Percent' (orange) data first and then '2 Percent' (blue), whereas the legend displays '2 Percent' (blue) first and then the '1 percent' (orange).

Is there a property that controls the order?